# How do I print my postman returned JSON array on my html using jQuery Ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I wish to loop through my JSON array returned by my API `[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3},{"d":4}]`. How do parse the JSON key and value onto my html so the output div gives only the key and value.

```
<body> 
  <div id = "result" style = "color:green" ></div>      
  <script type = "text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

          $.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost:8080/api/",
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(res) {
                  console.log(res);

                  //var data=$.parseJSON(res);
                  //var data = JSON.stringify(res)

                  $.each(res, function(key, value) {
                      console.log(key);
                      console.log(value);

                      var para = document.createElement("P");
                      para.innerHTML = key + ":" + value;

                      document.getElementById("result").appendChild(para);
                  })
              }
          });
      }) 
  </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: show result from console.log(res);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through array ,function will take arguments as `item` and `index`:

```
$.each(array, function(index,item){});
```

Make a secondary loop and iterate through objects:

```
$.each(object, function(key,value){});
```

```js
res = [{
    "a": 1
}, {
    "b": 2
}, {
    "c": 3
}, {
    "d": 4
}]
$.each(res, function(index,item) {
$.each(item, function(key,value){
    var para = document.createElement("P");
    para.innerHTML = key + ":" + value;
    document.body.appendChild(para);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format is an array, with each key an object

```
[
  {"a" : 1},
  {"b" : 2},
  {"c" : 3},
  {"d" : 4}
]
```

So this means that when you loop through the items, the `key` will be the index of the array, and the `value` will be the object

```js
 $.each(res, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key); // -> will be 0, 1, 2 etc
    console.log(value); // -> will be {"a" : 1}, {"b" : 2}, etc
});
```

So there are 2 options, you can either change your API to return a single object with the key:value pairs like this

```
{
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2,
    "c" : 3,
    "d" : 4
}
```

Or you need to add an extra loop in your code, so that you can loop through the objects and display the values (although I would recommend to rather go with the first option

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/api/",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
        $.each(res, function(key, object) {
            $.each(object, function(key, value) {
                var para = document.createElement("P");
                para.innerHTML = key+ ":" +value;
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(para);
            });
        });
    }
});
```